# Hide "Mail" in emacs mode line

Tags: emacs, elisp

This is small stuff but I haven't been able to figure it out:

How do I hide "Mail" from the mode line in emacs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just don't enable `display-time-mode`.

If you do want time, but not `Mail`, set `display-time-mail-string` to an empty string:

```
(setq display-time-mail-string "")
```

or, better yet:

```
(custom-set-variables '(display-time-mail-string ""))
```

Comment: So would that be `(set display-time-mail-string 0)`

Comment: @Andreas: empty string is `""`, not `0`.